# Module not found for lambda layer (AWS, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-cdk

I have a serverless application that uses CDK. I want to add a lambda layer to share some functionality across different areas of the application.

I define the layer in a CDK stack using

```js
const encryptLayer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'encrypt-layer', {
  compatibleRuntimes: [
    lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
  ],
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname,'src/Layers/EncryptDecryptFunctions')),
  description: 'shared functions to encrypt/decrypt data using asymmetric key'
});
```

and I added `encryptLayer` to a few of the functions in the same stack using the `layers` attribute when calling `new lambda.Function()...`. I deployed this and I see the layer sitting under the correct function in the console.

The file structure for the layer is

```
src
   Layers
      EncryptFunctions
         nodejs
            encrypt.js
            package.json
```

and I am trying to import it using
`const { encrypt } = require("/opt/nodejs/encrypt")` per the AWS documentation. However, I am getting a module not found exception when running the lambda that uses the encrypt method.

Is there anything else I need to do so that I can use the layer's code in my lambdas? For both code in the same repository and in a different repository?

Answer (score 1):

This seems an issue of PATH. As shown in this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-upload), paths for each Lambda runtime of Node.js are:

- `nodejs/node_modules`
- `nodejs/node14/node_modules (NODE_PATH)`

Therefore, you can add `node_modules/` direcitory. Use `nodejs/node_modules/` instead of `nodejs` in the file structure.

And import in lambda code will be like:

```
const encrypt = require('encrypt')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that I was bundling my lambdas using webpack and I didn't add '/opt/nodejs/encrypt' to my externals in webpack config. Doing that fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a serverless framework where you can define all in yml file like the below code.

```
layers:
  AnalyticsShared:
    path: node_modules
    name: analytics-shared-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    description: "Shared node modules for analytics"


functions:
  track:
    handler: analytics.queue
    timeout: 30
    layers:
      - {Ref: AnalyticsSharedLambdaLayer}
```

Ref URLs: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/layers